# BluePrism Decision Stage Issue

Tags: blueprism

I have a decision stage using [Current Claim Type] = "DirectPayment".
My data item currently has the value DirectPayment. However, the decision takes the no path. If I try evaluating then the result is true. If I delete the "DirectPayment" and re-type it the decision will then work. However, when I re run it will not work. I have tried trimming the data item but this has done nothing. Turning all text to lowercase also had no effect.

Comment: Your question is properly comprehensive, but since we're talking about wonky BP would it be possible to get screen shots?

Comment: There might be blank characters in your variable called [Current Claim Type] that you are not noticing, such as a space or a newline (or something along those lines). You can try trimming `Trim([Current Claim Type]) = "DirectPayment"` to resolve that issue, if it's indeed the issue. Newlines are often picked up when BP reads from Excel I've noticed.

Comment: Aside: this is absolutely an issue that I'd involve Blue Prism account support directly with.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like some really hard to find needle in haystack. You may need to investigate the string sign by sign to identify why the strings don't much.

I'd maybe suggest to use InStr() function here, as it can fix some issues in the same way the Trim() can. Instead of:

```
[Current Claim Type] = "DirectPayment"
```

I'd use this formula:

```
Instr([Current Claim Type],"DirectPayment")>0
```

Answer (score 0):

The below statement avoids if any there is any small/upper case letter in the string mismatch, And also the safe way to check the string as some times we type small cases when we are hard coding values

```
Upper([Current Claim Type]) = Upper("DirectPayment")
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers provided are pretty good however one thing not mentioned is you should also consider the Trim function. It's quite possible wherever you read your data from has some non breaking space character at the end that you can't see. Slim chance but it's a possibility especially when reading from html sourced data. Consider checking the length of the data item, it should be DirectPayment is length 13 however if it's greater then it's possible you have extra characters in the text you can't see with your eyes but the code can see. Trim would fix most of these